# Replacing NULL with various text strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table #CustomersStates that has the following columns: Year,Month,Day,Country,State,Customers

Where it lists how many customers are from each state each day. However when a day has zero customers, Country, State and Customers show NULL.

I know how to make the NULL in Customers show 0 using a case when statement,
but is there a way that I can insert each possible combination of country and state as new rows if there is NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a LEFT JOIN with a table (or table variable) that contains all the dates.

```
DECLARE @d TABLE
(
     Year INT,
     Month INT,
     Day INT
)

INSERT INTO @d (Year, Month, Day)
    ... -- populate the table variable

DECLARE @s TABLE
(
     State VARCHAR(50),
     Country VARCHAR(50)
)

-- populates states

SELECT *
FROM @d d
CROSS JOIN @s s
LEFT JOIN CustomersStates c ON d.Year=c.Year AND d.Month=c.Month and d.Day=c.Day
```

By the way, instead of CASE WHEN for display 0 when it is NULL you can use ISNULL(columnName, 0)

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I'm already doing. This way the date shows up, but the other columns where there are no transactions appear as NULL

Comment: You want to display 0 instead of NULL for those rows?

Comment: Show me your query, please.

Comment: Then you also need to define a table variable with all the country/State and do a cross join between dates and states. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark my answer as correct if that's what you think.